# get substring with between parenthesis using regex

Tags: regex, linux, shell

I have a bunch of lines as below:

```
PING planetlab2.tau.ac.il (192.114.4.3) 56(84) bytes of data.
```

I want to obtain the ip addresses from these lines, which are between the first `(` and `)` pair

how to get it using linux regex? like sed, grep, blabla
thanks!

Comment: Linux regex? You mean... like with grep?

Comment: What program? `sed`, `awk`, `grep`, etc.?

Comment: whatever is ok, as long as it can achieve my target

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
echo "PING planetlab2.tau.ac.il (192.114.4.3) 56(84) bytes of data." | sed -r 's/^[^(]+\(([^)]+)\).*/\1/'
192.114.4.3
```

Answer (score 0):

If You do not need the not matching lines and You only need the IP addresses from the matching lines try this:

```
perl -ne 'print $1 if /\(((?:\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3})\)/'<<EOT
PING planetlab2.tau.ac.il (192.114.4.3) 56(84) bytes of data.
EOT
```

Output:

```
192.114.4.3
```

Comment: I want to do it in a shell `while do done << infile` loop, how to embed this script in it? I don't understand EOT here